# How do I resolve the "MMC cannot initialize the snap-in" error in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, video, mmc

When I'm trying to add the "Windows Firewall With Advanced Security" Snap-in, I get this error message:

> MMC cannot initialize the snap-in

I searched for a solution but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this: [HERE](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/mmc-errors-how-can-i-fix-those-problrms-windows/a125a7f5-e1fe-417a-9ae7-4a8f4793a51e)

Hope this helps.

Step 1:

Stop and restart the Windows Firewall service

a)  Click Start, click in the Start Search box, type services.msc, and then press ENTER.

b)  Double click on “Windows Firewall” > Stop and restart the service

To specify the user account that the service can use to log on, click the Log On tab, and then do one of the following:

c)  Specify your user account to use the service, click  This account, click Browse, and then specify your user account in the Select User dialog box. When you are finished, click OK.

d)  Type the password for the user account in  Password and in Confirm password, and then click OK.

Step 2:

Try performing system restore and check:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/system-restore

Step 3:

If nothing helps, I suggest you to run SFC scan to find missing or corrupt files that may be causing this issue.

System File Checker (SFC) checks that all Windows 7 system files are where they should be as they were by default and not corrupted, changed, or damaged.

a.    Click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories, right-click Command Prompt, and  select Run as Administrator.

b.   Click Continue or supply Administrator credentials if prompted.

c.    In the Command Prompt window type the following, and press Enter:

sfc /scannow

d.   You should see the following on-screen message:

Beginning the system scan. This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.

Verification % complete.

e.   Once the scan has completed, test to see whether the issue that you are experiencing is resolved or not.

Refer the KB article for more information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Comment: If i tell you that I have tried all of those tips and all didn't fix the problem... infact i won't Reinstall the system...

Comment: Oh man I am sorry... checking to see if I can find something else

Comment: I haven't been able to find a ting... sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

Use your Windows 7 DVD and simply UPGRADE and be done with it.

You won't lose any of your programs.  Otherwise you will get the runaround from the internet.  Oh and make sure your DVD is set to run in Windows Vista SP2 mode (right click setup.exe to change).  Three hours later everything is fixed.  If you don't have a product key to enter at the end, you will only have limited access.  If you don't have a Windows 7 installer DVD, then you are screwed unless you buy a new OS.